# Bedeutung der Redewendung „Tomaten auf den Ohren haben“

Tags: phrase

Während ich die Serie Breaking Bad (1x7) sah, hörte ich den folgenden Satz:

> *Hast du Tomaten auf den Ohren? Ich hab langsam gesagt!*

Ich kenne die Redewendung *„Tomaten auf den Augen haben“* und [ihre Bedeutung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tomaten_auf_den_Augen_haben), aber ich kann nicht richtig verstehen, was *„Tomaten auf den Ohren haben“* bedeuten soll, und wieso *„Tomaten“*.

Comment: Ich kenne [Bohnen in die Ohr’n](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvpBBLn1Hn4)

Answer (score 2):

For my understanding, your

> Tomaten auf den Ohren haben

it is simply a humorous ad-hoc variation of the quite common idiom

> Tomaten auf den Augen haben

I even would not take the detour via *Möhren in den Ohren haben* (see the other answer on this page), as *Möhren in den Ohren haben* is very rare, and is farer away from *Tomaten auf den Augen haben*, as not one but two elements are replaced (*Augen* by *Ohren*, *Tomaten* by *Möhren*).

Unnecessary to add that the meaning would be "not hearing" or "not listening".

As for etymology, one opinion published by *Duden* is that *Tomaten auf den Augen* refers to someone having red puffy eyes due to some infection or whatever, and therefore not being able to see properly. I personally am sceptical about this explanation, but I do not have a better one so far.

Regarding what produce people are sticking into their ears, parsley should be more relevant than carrots. There is a famous scene in Asterix where Roman soldiers get into a habit of sticking parsley into their ears due to some misunderstanding. This again refers to on an old household remedy to treat earache with parsley.

Comment: Ein Deutscher stellt in einem Deutschforum eine Frage über eine Aspekt der deutschen Sprache. Dabei formuliert er die Frage in seiner Muttersprache Deutsch. Ein anderer Deutscher, der sich gut mit Deutsch auskennt, beantwortet diese Frage. Lasst uns raten: In welcher Sprache wird er wohl die Antwort schreiben?

Answer (score 1):

*»Tomaten auf den Ohren haben«* ist im Deutschen keine bekannte Redewendung, um *»nichts hören«* auszudrücken. Immerhin gibt es aber – wenn auch selten verwendet –

> *»auf den Ohren sitzen«* (umgangssprachlich: nicht aufpassen, nicht hören,
>   wenn jemand etwas sagt)
>   <sub>Quelle: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ohr)</sub>

Umgeschrieben würde das Filmzitat also lauten:

> Sitzt du auf den Ohren? Ich hab *langsam* gesagt!

Man könnte aber auch so übersetzen:

> Hast du Dreck in den Ohren? Ich hab *langsam* gesagt!

---

Wieso Tomaten?

In meinem Brockaus von 2003 heißt es:

> *Tomaten auf den Augen haben:* Die umgangssprachliche Wendung bedeutete
>   ursprünglich »übernächtigt, verschlafen aussehen« und bezog sich auf
>   die geröteten Bindehäute und verquollenen Augenpartien. Mit der Zeit
>   hat sich die Bedeutung dann gewandelt, heute steht der Ausdruck für
>   »nichts sehen; etwas nicht bemerken, übersehen«.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a variation of [http://www.dict.cc/forum-questions/detail-767136-möhren-in-den-ohren.html](http://www.dict.cc/forum-questions/detail-767136-m%C3%B6hren-in-den-ohren.html)

Having carrots in the ears makes more sense as they in theory stick, if they are small enough. Tomatoes however would fall to the ground if they are only "on" the ears.

So it's not really technically accurate. But it's easy to emphasize and shout Tomaten. Making the T real sharp. To sound more aggressive. You can't really do that with the M of Möhren to the same extent.